# ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying out the new ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features. I made a simple app with just one controller (HomeController) and one view (Index). I also added a mobile version of the index view.

```
Views/Home/Index.cshtml
Views/Home/Index.Mobile.cshtml
```

When launching the application in a desktop browser the regular view is shown as expected, however when I launch the application in the [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/) as a Samsung Galaxy S, I still get the regular view and not the mobile version.

the user agent string sent from the emulator looks like this:

```
Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; Opera Mobi/23731; U; en) Presto/2.9.201 Version/11.50
```

Any ideas on why this is not working?

**Update**
Thanks to @nemesv I was able to solve the problem, here is my current solution, hopefully it will cover most mobile scenarios.

```
public class MobileDisplayMode : DefaultDisplayMode
{
    private readonly StringCollection _useragenStringPartialIdentifiers = new StringCollection
    {
        "Android",
        "Mobile",
        "Opera Mobi",
        "Samsung",
        "HTC",
        "Nokia",
        "Ericsson",
        "SonyEricsson",
        "iPhone"
    };

    public MobileDisplayMode() : base("Mobile")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context => IsMobile(context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()));
    }

    private bool IsMobile(string useragentString)
    {
        return _useragenStringPartialIdentifiers.Cast<string>()
                    .Any(val => useragentString.IndexOf(val, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }
}
```

And i Global.asax

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new MobileDisplayMode());
```

Comment: life saver. its actually stupid that the tutorial does not say this. It just feels so half ass from microsofts side. They usually are on point with their tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, though StringCollection does seem to be one of the most useless classes ever. Not only does it offer nothing in this code sample, nor performance, you have to write extra code (Cast<string>) for the pleasure of using it. Replace it with List<string> and live happily ever after

Answer (score 29, accepted):

ASP.Net (actually the `HttpBrowserCapabilitiesBase` class) doesn't recognize the Opera Mobile Emulator as a Mobile browser.

You can check this in any controller action: `HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`  will return `false` for the Opera Mobile browser.

Because the built in `DefaultDisplayMode` uses the following method to check mobile browsers you need to register your custom `DisplayMode` which correctly recognizes Opera Mobile.

To do this you need to add this to the Global.asax `Application_Start`:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
{
    ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent()
        .IndexOf("Opera Mobi", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great! as it turns out, it didn't recognize the default browser on a Samsung Galaxy S neither. I've been unable to find out exactly how the MVC 4 framework validates the user agent string. I implemented a class that hopefully will cover most  scenarios. I've updated the question with that code.

Comment: You should check out the free Keynote Mite desktop-based tool for testing and verification of mobile Web content application. It is an excellent mobile testing tool.

http://mite.keynote.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll do that

Comment: Fairly stupid that HttpBrowserCapabilities behaves like this, given that the MVC team *recommends* using Opera Mobile Browser Emulator... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features  Their Apple Safari User Agent string trick fails for the same reason, unless one creates an iPhone override.

Comment: Perfect answer! Did for me too.

Answer (score 0):

a solution for all mobiles without a need to specify all browser names will be like this...

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0,
             new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
             {
                 ContextCondition = (ctx => (
                     (ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent() != null) && ctx.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
             ))
             });  
    }
```

Comment: Actually this won't work, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710026/how-does-mvc4-detect-a-mobile-browser the same code that makes Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice detect a mobile device is the same check that is done when choosing a mobile view to render.