# How to get current displaymode is mobile in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing mobile web application. I need to get current displaymode is mobile in controller.

My problem is: I have 2 partialview

```
/Views/Shared/ListItem.cshtml
/Views/Shared/ListItem.mobile.cshtml
```

when use **PartialView("ListItem")** this is correctly works. But i need to put partialviews in sub folder

```
/Views/Shared/Modules/Post/ListItem.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Modules/Post/ListItem.mobile.cshtml
```

When i use **PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Modules/Post/ListItem.cshtml")** this works on desktop. when displaymode is mobile, `ListItem.mobile.cshtml` not displayed.

My choice is

```
if( CurrentDisplayMode==Mobile){
  PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Modules/Post/ListItem.mobile.cshtml");
else
  PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Modules/Post/ListItem.cshtml");
```

How to get `CurrentDisplayMode` ?
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

I also needed to access the current display mode so I could adjust the view model that was passed to the view (less information in the mobile view thus it can be displayed from a smaller view model).

`ControllerContext.DisplayMode` cannot be used because it will be set after the action has executed.

So you have to determine the display mode based on the context (user agent, cookie, screen size, etc...)

Here's a [nice trick I found on the ASP.NEt forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1864999.aspx/1?DisplayMode%20null%20in%20ControllerContext) that will let you determine the display mode using the same logic that will later be used by the framework:

```
public string GetDisplayModeId()
{
    foreach (var mode in DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes)
        if (mode.CanHandleContext(HttpContext))
            return mode.DisplayModeId;

    throw new Exception("No display mode could be found for the current context.");
}
```

Comment: This seems to answer the OP's question most accurately

Answer (score 1):

check the value of: HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice

Comment: GetOverridenBrowser is not found

Comment: Are you inside the controller or in the view? in the view you need to add viewcontext.httpcontex.....

Comment: Forgot to add that you do need to have the following using statement: 
using System.Web.WebPages;

Comment: I found Request.Browser().IsMobileDevice. But this won't work on android and other some phone.

Comment: This is solve my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614576/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-features

Answer (score 0):

I believe MS wants you to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.displaymode%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
controller.ControllerContext.DisplayMode
```

It works but I found two major problem with it (as of the date of this post):

1. Unit testing. DisplayMode property can not be set manually (throws NullReferenceException) and can not be mocked because it is not virtual.
2. It does not work with [MvcDonutCaching](http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/). DisplayMode simply returns NULL when requesting cached portion of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The best option you have is checking the Request headers user agent field where you can listen for android iPhone etc. While that wont give you screen size and isnt going to work if you are not listening for nokia phones or something like that, this is a solution and allows you to limit what you support as most companies do.