# How does MVC4 detect a mobile browser?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

I've just followed Scott Hanselmans tutorial on [making a switchable site in MVC4.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MakingASwitchableDesktopAndMobileSiteWithASPNETMVC4AndJQueryMobile.aspx)

I'm using the Opera mobile emulator to test as I don't have VS2102.

When rendering my page in the emulator `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` is false although it still renders the mobile view.

[image]

My questions are:

- Why/How does MVC4 decide to render the mobile view? It doesn't seem like it looks at `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`.
- Will the View Switcher be displayed on a real mobile device?

**Edit:**

I think I realised my mistake:

To get it to work with the opera emulator I added a `MobileDisplayMode` as described here: 
[ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614576/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-features)

It seems that that solution works with rendering correctly but `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` won't work. The same goes for `ViewContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice` is there a way to get around this?

Comment: EHMAGEHD, This post is from the future!!! *I'm using the Opera mobile emulator to test as I don't have VS2102.* :)

Comment: I see you mention you are using Opera Mobile to test. You can also use WebMatrix to emulate iPhone, iPad, WP7 etc. or in Chrome Ctrl Shift + i then Settings > Override and choose the UserAgent you want to send with the requests.

Comment: haha yep you caught me out...im working on a legacy mvc4 app, Microsoft fix browser detection in MVC11 :)

Comment: When changing user agents in chrome it doesn't render the mobile view at all

Answer (score 5):

MVC recognize Mobile device by matching the HTTP request header  with browser config files present in  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers

The asp.net MVC browser detection approach is not great so i recommend using some sort of DDR

Comment: I have a question, is it possible to override this configuration via browserCaps.config? NB: i am using 51degrees.mobi .