# How to override Browser.IsMobileDevice is ASP.NET MVC4 application?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile

I'm looking for a way to set `HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice` to true for custom mobile devices not dedected by MVC4 and 51degrees.mobi, which is also used in application.

I tried this in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice = true;
}
```

But I got a compile error:

> Property or indexer
>   'System.Web.Configuration.HttpCapabilitiesBase.IsMobileDevice' cannot
>   be assigned to -- it is read only

51degrees.mobi, jquery, jquery-ui and jquery-ui-mobile are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That property is set by the request sent by the client to the server in order for you to check the browser user agent on the server, that's why it's not allowed to change.

If you want to change the user agent on the server you need to add this line:

```
HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser(BrowserOverride.Mobile);
```

If you know you can set the user agent manually:

```
HttpContext.SetOverriddenBrowser("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7");
```

To clear the override you need to:

```
HttpContext.ClearOverriddenBrowser();
```

Have a look at this [page](http://blog.mirajavora.com/overriding-browser-capabilities-in-asp.net). Or how to override the default display mode in mvc in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614576/asp-net-mvc-4-mobile-features)

Comment: Thank you. If 51degrees.mobi module is added to application, it sets IsMobileDevice to true for additionally dedected devices. Why it is not allowed to change it from my application ?

Comment: Basically what they do is overwrite the default .net functionality. http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Documentation/NET/WebApplications/RequestBrowserOverwrites.aspx

Comment: They provide a list of browser user agents like mvc does but their list is fresher.

Comment: How to override Browser.IsMobileDevice in my application like 51degrees.mobile overrides it ? I changed application and replaced all Browser.IsMobileDevice calls  to custom function calls but maybe it is better on change .NET standard property value because in my change same version of OutputCache page is used for mobile and desktop devices